# For loop iteration missing values out?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to create a column in a pandas dataframe, that creates a counter that equals the number of rows in the dataframe, divided by 2. Here is my code so far:

```
# Fill the cycles column with however many rows exist / 2
for x in ((jac_output.index)/2):
    jac_output.loc[x, 'Cycles'] = x+1
```

However, I've noticed that it misses out values every so often, like this:

[[image: Missing Values1]

Why would my counter miss a value every so often as it gets higher? And is there another way of optimizing this, as it seems to be quite slow?

Answer (score 0):

you may have removed some data from the dataframe, so some indicies are missing, therefore you should use [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to renumber them, or you can just use

`for x in np.arange(0,len(jac_output.index),1)/2:`.

Comment: Thanks, but no matter what I do with reset_index or your suggestion, the for loop still misses a random value?

Answer (score 0):

You can view `jac_output.index` as a list like `[0, 1, 2, ...]`. When you divide it by 2, it results in `[0, 0.5, 1, ...]`. `0.5` is surely not in your original index.

To slice the index into half, you can try:

```py
jac_output.index[:len(jac_output.index)//2]
```